# primeng:p-table custom sort for date format DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm

Tags: angular, sorting, primeng

I work on angular4 and primeng `<p-table>`. My code has a table which displays a `courseComplete` column. The `courseComplete` displays date format as `DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm` which I need to sort. I did implement custom sort for  but sorting is not working as expected.

In ascending sort, data is coming as: (seems time is not getting properly sorted)

```
29.06.2018 03:11
29.06.2018 01:57
01.07.2018 05:35
```

Please guide me where did I go wrong in sorting. Below is my code: **( as of now date is in string format, should the type be changed? I am also using pagination, can this be the issue?)**

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="course" (sortFunction)="customSort($event)" [customSort]="true">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.date">
                Course Completed On
                <p-sortIcon [field]="col.date"></p-sortIcon>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>

customSort(event: SortEvent) {
        event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {
            let value1 = data1[event.field];
            let value2 = data2[event.field];
            let result = null;

            if (value1 == null && value2 != null)
                result = -1;
            else if (value1 != null && value2 == null)
                result = 1;
            else if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
                result = 0;
            else if (typeof value1 === 'string' && typeof value2 === 'string')
                result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
            else
                result = (value1 < value2) ? -1 : (value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0;

            return (event.order * result);
        });
    }
```

Comment: In this format "DD.MM.YYYY" you will always have your dates sorted by DAY first. You need to use Date type for you dates. Then you'll just add another "else if" to your custom sort:   else if (typeof value1 === 'Date' && typeof value2 === 'Date')
                result = (value1 < value2) ? -1 : (value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0; or even you can leave it like it is without changes - last "else" section should do the job

Comment: @Woworks, I tried this, still did not work. Below is my code i tried

Comment: @Anna - Did you made it work? Can you please post example?